# Critical directive not working inside sections in openmp

Tags: openmp

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

#pragma omp parallel  num_threads(2)
{


#pragma omp sections
 {

 #pragma omp section
     {

     #pragma omp cirtical
     {
     std::cout<<"first section is executed by thread "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<"\n";
     }
     }


 #pragma omp section
     {
    #pragma omp cirtical
     {
 std::cout<<"second section is executed by thread "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<"\n";
     }
     }

 }

  }
 return 0;
 }
```

In the above code output operation in two section have race between then although they are in critical section. Can you tell why this is happening and how should I ensure no race between them?

Comment: The mis-spelling of the word `critical` probably isn't helping.

Comment: Though you'd expect the compiler to complain; clang certainly does https://godbolt.org/z/eRHj_t though gcc (unhelpfully), does not.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost certainly that pointed out by High Performance Mark: you have mis-spelled the word "critical" in the OpenMP pragma.

However, this points out the more general issue that you should (at least) enable warnings when compiling. With GCC you can achieve that with `-Wall`, or, if you only want to be warned about this error, you can use `-Wunknown-pragmas`.

If you want to be both stricter and more selective you can use `-Werror=unknown-pragmas`, which will cause code like this with mis-spelled pragmas to fail to compile. The downside of any of these is that if you then compile the code without `-fopenmp` you get the warning/error for every OpenMP pragma.

You may, therefore, want to enable `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` only when you also have `-fopenmp`. (This should be simple to do in Make; how easy it is in "simple","modern" build systems, I have no idea :-)).

Thanks to High Performance Mark for the original answer, and to Jakub Jelinek for GCC argument education.

Comment: Throwing an error by default like Clang does is a bit tricky. The OpenMP specifications says nothing about handling of unrecognised directives. This is likely intentional in order to support partial forward compatibility.

Comment: AIUI the LLVM approach is 1) when compiling with OpenMP enabled, error on unrecognised OpenMP pragmas. 2) when compiling without OpenMP enabled treat all pragmas that start with "omp" as being OK and don't complain about them. That seems a reasonable compromise, since erroneous OpenMP pragmas can't cause a problem until you're compiling with OpenMP.

Comment: What I mean is that erroneous OpenMP directives are indistinguishable from future OpenMP directives. But I guess the all or nothing approach is better than silent partial support when it comes to correctness.

Comment: "What I mean is that erroneous OpenMP directives are indistinguishable from future OpenMP directives." Sure, but if the compiler doing the compilation doesn't support that future feature, I want an error, not silent acceptance of "#pragma omp rainbow unicorn", because in the context of the current compilation something is definitely wrong.